# CABasicAnimation runs after Implicit Animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I want a layer to behave like this:

[image: correct]

Instead, it behaves like this:

[image: improper]

The card flip animation is created by two `CABasicAnimation`s applied in a `CAAnimationGroup`. The incorrect spin effect happens because the implicit animation from the `CALayer` property change runs first and then my animation specified in the `CABasicAnimation` runs. How can I stop the implicit animation from running so that only my specified animation runs?

Here's the relevant code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var simpleLayer = CALayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    simpleLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2 - 50, y: view.bounds.height / 2 - 50), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    simpleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    view.layer.addSublayer(simpleLayer)
  }

  func handleTap() {
    let xRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    xRotation.toValue = 0
    xRotation.byValue = M_PI

    let yRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    yRotation.toValue = 0
    yRotation.byValue = M_PI

    simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.x")

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [xRotation, yRotation]
    group.duration = 0.6
    group.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    simpleLayer.addAnimation(group, forKey: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually not positive if `setValue(_:forKeyPath:)` is monitored by Core Animation to activate implicit animations or not. If you surround those two function calls with a [`CATransaction` that disables actions](http://calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/17/catransaction-in-depth.html#preventing-animations-from-occurring), does that fix the problem?

Comment: Thank you, @LucasTizma! That was the correct code. I described it fully in an answer below.

Comment: I received a downvote on the original question, so now the value is "-1". I'm not sure why I received the downvote. If the downvoter could comment, I'd be happy to address his or her concern. This isn't as specific a use case as it might seem. This question is generically applicable. Unless you add the code to disable the implicit animation, the CAAnimationGroup does not behave as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LucasTizma had the correct answer.

Surround your animation with `CATransaction.begin(); CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)` and `CATransaction.commit()`. This will [disable the implicit animation](http://calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/17/catransaction-in-depth.html#preventing-animations-from-occurring) and make the `CAAnimationGroup` animate correctly.

Here's the final result:

[image: triangle flip animation]

This is the important snippet of code in Swift 3:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

let xRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
xRotation.toValue = 0
xRotation.byValue = M_PI

let yRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
yRotation.toValue = 0
yRotation.byValue = M_PI

simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.y")

let group = CAAnimationGroup()
group.animations = [xRotation, yRotation]
simpleLayer.add(group, forKey: nil)

CATransaction.commit()
```

And this is the full code for the depicted animation with an iOS app:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var simpleLayer = CALayer()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let ratio: CGFloat = 1 / 5
    let viewWidth = view.bounds.width
    let viewHeight = view.bounds.height
    let layerWidth = viewWidth * ratio
    let layerHeight = viewHeight * ratio

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: viewWidth / 2 - layerWidth / 2,
                                      y: viewHeight / 2 - layerHeight / 2),
                      size: CGSize(width: layerWidth, height: layerHeight))

    let topRightPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0)
    let bottomRightPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height)
    let topLeftPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    let linePath = UIBezierPath()

    linePath.move(to: topLeftPoint)
    linePath.addLine(to: topRightPoint)
    linePath.addLine(to: bottomRightPoint)
    linePath.addLine(to: topLeftPoint)

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = linePath.cgPath

    simpleLayer.frame = rect
    simpleLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    simpleLayer.mask = maskLayer

    // Smooth antialiasing
    // * Convert the layer to a simple bitmap that's stored in memory
    // * Saves CPU cycles during complex animations
    // * Rasterization is set to happen during the animation and is disabled afterwards
    simpleLayer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    view.layer.addSublayer(simpleLayer)
  }

  func handleTap() {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
      self.simpleLayer.shouldRasterize = false
    })

    simpleLayer.shouldRasterize = true

    let xRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    xRotation.toValue = 0
    xRotation.byValue = M_PI

    let yRotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.y")
    yRotation.toValue = 0
    yRotation.byValue = M_PI

    simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.x")
    simpleLayer.setValue(M_PI, forKeyPath: "transform.rotation.y")

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [xRotation, yRotation]
    group.duration = 1.2
    group.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    simpleLayer.add(group, forKey: nil)

    CATransaction.commit()
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! As a side note, you should be able to fix those aliased edges by rasterizing the layer (and setting the rasterization scale to the main screen's scale) during animation.

Comment: Thank you @LucasTizma. That also worked well! I added the code for smooth antialiasing to the answer. 

Comment: Ideally, you only rasterize during animation and disable it after. You can use transactions once again [to know when your animations are all done](http://calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/17/catransaction-in-depth.html#getting-notified-when-animations-finish) so you can disable rasterization.

Comment: @LucasTimza That makes sense. I edited the answer again to incorporate that change. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score -1):

You are creating 2 separate animations and applying them in an animation group. When you do that they are applied as 2 discrete steps.

It looks like that's not what you want. If not, then don't create 2 separate animations, one on transform.rotation.x and the other on transform.rotation.y. Instead, concatenate both changes onto a transformation matrix and apply the changed transformation matrix as a single animation.

Comment: With your feedback, I tried this code, but it's still not right: https://gist.github.com/benmorrow/174e4f16053ac979ed62cee0d82c9560

Comment: Try applying first a PI rotation around x, then a PI rotation around y, to the transform. That's not the same thing as a PI rotation along the 1,1,0 to 0,0,0 line.

Comment: Yes, you were right. This effect is almost there. I updated the Gist from the previous comment if you'd like to see the new code. However, the effect I'm looking for is still not there because the animation it generates is equivalent to a rotation around the z-axis. Here's a gif of that: http://i.imgur.com/FpQMOHy.gifv I'm looking for the front face to back face flip like in the first GIF in the main question

Comment: That isn't true. `CAAnimationGroup` doesn't commit its animations in sequence. They're applied at the same time (or relative to each animation's `beginTime`).